# W1035 Return value of function 'Test' might be undefined unexpectedly appears after adding a try-finally block

Tags: delphi, compiler-warnings, delphi-xe7

I have an unexpected W1035 on compiling:

> [dcc32 Warning] Unit1.pas(40): W1035 Return value of function 'Test'
> might be undefined

```
function CheckFn() : Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
end;

function Test() : Boolean;
begin
  try
    if(not CheckFn()) then
      raise Exception.Create('Error Message');

    Result := True;
  finally

  end;
end;
```

If I remove the `try-finally` block, then the warning disappears.

```
function Test() : Boolean;
begin
  if(not CheckFn()) then
    raise Exception.Create('Error Message');

  Result := True;
end;
```

Why is this happening? (Bug?)

Comment: Similar problem with an exception raised in `try-finally` block: `var Tmp : Integer; begin try raise Exception.Create('Invalid value!'); finally end; ShowMessage(IntToStr(Tmp)); end;`. It raises a warning on compiling _W1036 Variable 'Tmp' might not have been initialized_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's analyse `Test`.

1. If `CheckFn` raises an exception, you immediately go to the `finally` clause, and then you leave the function without returning a value.
2. Otherwise, if `CheckFn` returns `True`, you will return `True` from the function.
3. Otherwise, if `CheckFn` returns `False`, you will raise an exception and immediately go to the `finally` clause and then you leave the function without returning a value.

Hence, in all cases when this function does return a value, it is defined (specifically, it is `True`). Therefore, the compiler is wrong to emit this warning.

And, indeed, in Delphi 10.4, no warning is produced for this code.

(Or, just possibly, did you confuse `finally` with `except`? If so, the compiler is right.)

Comment: No, I didn't confused, it's really a `finally`

Comment: Then it's a bug in the compiler!

Comment: I'm glad to hear that it has been already fixed in newer IDEs. I'll add an useless initialization with a todo-comment for removing it as soon as I will upgrade my IDE

Comment: FWIW the fix for this particular issue happened somewhen during the 10.2.x version (10.1.2 gives the bogus W1035, 10.2.3 does not)